# Converting a JSON sting into an object as if it were received from an API

Tags: json, api, rest, axios

I have a VueJS application which makes this API request:

```
  this.$axios
    .get('/api/v1/something/endpoint')
    .then(success => {
      self.holdings = success.data
    })
    .finally(() => {
      self.searched = true
    })
```

I have captured the JSON response from the browser Network tab in the PROD environment and I want to replace the `success.data` value with this JSON locally.

This does not work by simply dropping in the JSON as a string, I assume because the axios library is performing a JSON to Object conversion.

How can I drop this response in as though it were the actual API response so I can test locally with production data?

Nb. Pointing my local machine at the production API is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I just loaded the JSON blob from a local file:

```
import _json from '@/assets/holdings.json'
```

and replaced the incoming data with that loaded object:

```
self.holdings = _json
```